# Express validator isIn function not work properly

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, validation

I have a problem with `isIn` function from `express-validator`, here is my code:

```
const genres = [
  "Comedy",
  "Fantasy",
  "Crime"
]


///
    body("genres")
      .exists()
      .withMessage("Genre is Required")
      .isArray()
      .withMessage("Genres must be an array of Strings")
      .isIn(genres)
      .withMessage("Genre contain invalid value.")
```

and now I explain what is not working correctly,

when i send:

```
{
    "genres":[ "Comedy", "Fantasy" ]
}
```

then all is OK and my validator not return me any errors,

when I send:

```
{
    "genres":[ "Test" ]
}
```

then validator return me error and this is good,

but when I send this:

```
{
    "genres":[ "Comedy", "Test" ]
}
```

then... my validator not return me any error but he should because I have no `Test` element in my `genres` array :/, can someone tell me what is wrong here? It looks like, the validator need only one correct value from array to return `true` here ...

here is my validator:

```
function validator(req, res, next) {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    const extractedErrors = []
    errors.array().map(err => extractedErrors.push({ [err.param]: err.msg }))
  
    return res.json({
      errors: extractedErrors
    })
  }

  next();
}
```

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Express-validator wraps the validator.js library, from the document of validator.js [here](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js)

> isIn(str, values) check if the string is in a array of allowed values.

Source code [here](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js/blob/master/src/lib/isIn.js)

The method is applied only for **string**, not array. It looks like the library only cares about the first item in your array. This input gives me the error

```
{
    "genres":[ "Test" , "Comedy"]
}
```

Comment: So this is a bug in this library, this not should work like this

Comment: I don't think so. This is written in the documentation so it's expected. You can do a pull request or discuss with them anyway.

Comment: Moreover: "[*Since validator.js only accepts string as input, any value (including arrays and objects) that needs to be validated by a Standard Validator is first converted to such type.*](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#standard-validators)". Which of course totally contrasts `isArray()`. And no, it doesn't care only about the first item in the array, it coerces the array to a string - `["Test"]` becomes `"Test"`, `["Test", "Comedy"]` becomes `"Test,Comedy"`. Looks like you need a `.custom()` validator that checks *every* element of the array.

Comment: @Bergi, when I test with ["Comedy, "Test"] this doesn't return any error. So I don't think the array coerces to a string. Totally agree with the custom validator in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use `options` in place of `genres` and use a comma-separated string in place of an array. See example below

```
{
    "options": "Test,Comedy"
}
```

if you have an `array` you can perform `array.join()` see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) for more info